# What cookies are sent by the JVM to the server when running a Java applet?

Tags: java, cookies, applet

On my web server I have an HTML file that contains an applet tag:

```
<html>
  <head/>
  <body>
    <applet code="Hello.class" width="100" height="100" />
  </body>
</html>
```

And I have a Java class file named Hello.class in the same directory as the HTML file.

Both of these files are running on a web server (IIS 6) whose host name is something like this:

```
bart.simpson.springfield.com
```

I have two cookies in my browser:

- CookieA - Scoped to springfield.com
- CookieB - Scoped to simpson.springfield.com

When the HTML file is requested from the server, Fiddler shows that both of the above cookies are sent along with the request.

When the Java class file is requested from the server, Fiddler shows that only CookieA (scoped to springfield.com) is sent.

I need *both* cookies to be sent to the server.  Is there a way to do this?

I'm seeing this behavior is Firefox 3.5.2 and IE 7.

I've tried to find the spec on which cookies are sent but turned up nothing since Java 1.3.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't actually know anything about the implementation, but if it uses `java.net.URL` internally, I wonder if `springfield.com` and `simpson.springfield.com` resolve to the same IP address.

Comment: In my case, springfield.com and simpson.springfield.com have different IP addresses.  I don't think that the cookies a browser sends to a server have anything to do with IP addresses but has everything to do with the domain names of the cookies.

Comment: I've done some research on the RFC for cookies (http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2965.html) and, to the extent I understand the legalese, it sounds like both cookies should be sent because they both match the domain name.

Comment: Just to clarify, my problem had nothing to do with how many parts were in the domain names.  It was just a coincidence that all of the cookies from simpson.springfield.com had the HttpOnly tag on them and none of the cookies from springfield.com had HttpOnly tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client-side Java plug-in always consults the browser to verify if a cookie needs to be sent in the request. Details of the cookie support in the Java plug-in are available in the [Java deployment guide](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/cookie_support.html).

There is one situation though where cookies will not be sent, and that is when the web server has set the [HttpOnly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) flag on the cookie. In such a case, the HTTP request for the applet class will not contain the cookie header, since the Java plug-in will not be able to access the cookie.

Comment: Vineet, I had the HttpOnly flag set on the cookies that weren't being sent.  Removing that flag fixed my problem.  Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. Just faced the same problem a few weeks back.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie for HTML file is sent by browser itself but the cookie for applet class file is sent by Java Plugin. So they often differ.

For browser, the only rule it uses is the domain name. Plugin has to factor in things as security policy and codebase. See this document for the details,

http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.3/docs/cookie.html

What's your codebase for the applet?

Comment: ZZ Coder, thank you for your reply.  In this instance it was an issue of the HttpOnly flag being set.